# Enum of types in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am currently in the process of converting a project to TypeScript. I have this Algorithm object which contains a getRun function and an edgesRepresentation string which contains information about how the edges are represented (`"adjacencyList" | "adjacencyMatrix" | "edgeList"`, though only `"adjacencyList"` is being used now). I do not want to make the IAlgorithm interface a generic for the edgesRepresentation if possible (as I see no reason for the Algorithm to be a generic just because its run function is one too) so I'm preferably looking for a more dynamic solution. The problem is, when IAlgorithm has a getRun function that returns a run function, the run function (which I have no problem making a generic) needs to have assumptions about the way edges are represented, but those are different for different edgesRepresentation objects. I want to have something similar to this:

```
interface IAlgorithm {
    getRun: (arg0: {considers: Considers, setIsDone: (arg0?: boolean)=>void}) => IRunType;
}

export interface IRunType<T extends EdgesRepresentationType> {
    (nodesIds: List<string>, edgeList: T):void;
}

type AdjacencyListType = Map<string, Map<string, typeof EdgeRecord>>;

export enum EdgesRepresentationType {
    adjacencyList=AdjacencyListType
}
```

Here EdgeRecord is just an immutable Record containing information about an edge.

Something like that would be good as well:

```
interface IAlgorithm<T extends EdgesRepresentationType> {
    getRun: (arg0: {considers: Considers, setIsDone: (arg0?: boolean)=>void}) => IRunType<T>;
}

export type ITopSort = IAlgorithm<EdgesRepresentationType.adjacencyList>;

export interface IRunType<T extends EdgesRepresentationType> {
    (nodesIds: List<string>, edgeList: T):void;
}

type AdjacencyListType = Map<string, Map<string, typeof EdgeRecord>>;

export enum EdgesRepresentationType {
    adjacencyList=AdjacencyListType
}
```

I just cannot find a way for this to work, although my TypeScript knowledge is fairly limited.

Comment: You show 2 thing you want but not what you have or what's wrong with those two. Can you explain what's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand your problem correctly, but if yes, then why not using [type union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#defining-a-union-type), like so:

```js
type AdjacencyListType = Map<string, Map<string, typeof EdgeRecord>>;
export type EdgesRepresentationType = AdjacencyListType | AdjacencyMatrix | EdgeList;
```

I'm aware this will make the `IAlgorithm` kind of generic, but narrowed down to some of types only, but at some point you **will** have to `if` or `switch` between types passed to it's function even when using enum-like solution.

Speaking of which:
I don't think that enum of types explicitly is a possible solution, as anything regarding the custom type will most likely be a computed type.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't realize this was a feature of the language and researching it didn't help!